# How JQGrid loads icons from single file

Tags: jqgrid, icons

When I searched for the icons used by JQGrid, I found single PNG file with all the icons. I am wondering how it can use portion of the image as icon for buttons used in JQGrid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jqGrid uses icons from jQuery UI Theme. Usage of multiple icons (pictures) in one PNG file is the standard optimization. If one separate icons in multiple files then loading of enery separate file follow long time because of round trip times. Even is multiple files will be loaded parallel (multiple parallel HTTP request) loading of one file is more effectively.

So it you examine jquery-ui.css of jQuery UI (for example [here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css)) you will find the following

```css
/* Icons
----------------------------------*/

/* states and images */
.ui-icon {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.ui-icon,
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_469bdd_256x240.png);
}
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_d8e7f3_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-default .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_6da8d5_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon,
.ui-state-focus .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_217bc0_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-active .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_f9bd01_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-highlight .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-error .ui-icon,
.ui-state-error-text .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png);
}

/* positioning */
.ui-icon-blank { background-position: 16px 16px; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-n { background-position: 0 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-ne { background-position: -16px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-e { background-position: -32px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-se { background-position: -48px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-s { background-position: -64px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-sw { background-position: -80px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-w { background-position: -96px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-nw { background-position: -112px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-2-n-s { background-position: -128px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-2-e-w { background-position: -144px 0; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-n { background-position: 0 -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-ne { background-position: -16px -16px; }
...
```

Every row of the body of the grid have the class "ui-widget-content". So the icons will be from the image with the relative URL `images/ui-icons_469bdd_256x240.png` (see CSS rule for `.ui-widget-content .ui-icon`):

[image]

On the other side the pager have the class "ui-state-default". So the icons will be from the image with the relative URL `images/ui-icons_6da8d5_256x240.png` (see CSS rule for `.ui-state-default .ui-icon`) and so on.

So all icons will be loaded from **one file**. All icon have the same height and the width `16px`, but different icons have **different `background-position`**. So different 16x16 px parts of the index will be used.

The optimization method have the name *Image Sprites*. You can read about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp). There are some server solution which allows to combine many images (PNG and GIF images, but not JPG) referenced from a CSS file into a single large image *on the fly* on the server (see [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-image-sprite)). There are also places in Internet (like [here](http://css.spritegen.com/)) which allows you to upload multiple files and to get one combined image. In any way the solution is very old already and it will be intensively used by web developers.